# Android app crashes when using AsyncTask for fetching an url with jsoup

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup, assets

So the app shows up the dialog while loading but then crashes. Te reason I decided t use these technologies is because I have to load an html, which changes dynamically and there are heavy CSS files which I would like to cache, so I think including them as assets is a good idea. I use Jsoup because I am able to get the html page without having to download the full content.
Here's the code:

```
public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

ProgressDialog mProgress;
WebView webview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_fragment, container,
            false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    String url = bundle.getString("url");

    webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading",
            "Please wait for a moment...");
    fetchUrl thread = (fetchUrl) new fetchUrl().execute();
    Document doc = thread.getDoc();
    String htmlData = null;
    doc.head().getElementsByTag("link").remove();
    doc.head().appendElement("link").attr("rel", "stylesheet").attr("type", "text/css").attr("href", "style.css");
    htmlData = doc.outerHtml();
    //TODO fetchURL here
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///assets/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

   // webview.loadUrl(url);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //TODO add assets loading he instead of urlLoad
            //view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

The class extending AsybcTask:

```
    private class fetchUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document>{
    Document doc;
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... param) {
        try {
          doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.ch").userAgent("Chrome").get();//use url when ready
        } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
        return doc;   
    }


}
```

And the error log:

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125): Process: com.flexenergy.swapp, PID: 5125
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flexenergy.swapp/com.flexenergy.swapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.nodes.Element org.jsoup.nodes.Document.head()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.nodes.Element org.jsoup.nodes.Document.head()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at com.flexenergy.swapp.MyWebViewFragment.onCreateView(MyWebViewFragment.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)   
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5125):    ... 10 more
W/ActivityManager( 1219):   Force finishing activity 1 com.flexenergy.swapp/.MainActivity
I/Choreographer( 1219): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/EGL_emulation(  919): tid 919: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: please add crash stack trace...

Comment: I don't know how to get the error in console since the app runs in the emulator and I don't get any output...

Comment: @nicolaszimerman Use logcat, Nicolas https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Please check have you add internet permission in mainfest or not?

Comment: @ItzikSamara here you go...it says jsoup null reference pointer

Comment: @praveenSharma yes the application was already using http connections, the problems arised when trying to use a new thread...and apparently is te only way and the right way to fetch an url while the page is created

Comment: @ItzikSamara basically I need to somehow get the document fetched in the thread, but I dont find a way...and I tried to load the document into the webview from the new thread but it becomes worse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is a concurrent process of your main thread so to use the result of that computation you need to wait until it completes his work.

You're trying to call `doc.head()` but doc is a null reference because the asyncTask has not completed, then has not initialized `doc`.

Do your stuff with `doc` in the `OnPostExecute(result)` method of the AsyncTask, in this way you'll be sure that `doc` is correctly initialized.

Comment: OK, but where can I return the doc then? Because I read that is the doInBackground method which can return something...I cant override onPostExecute for returning something...

Comment: Problem solved...I could insert 
"  webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///assets/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);  " into the onPostExecute method, while in the "doInBackground" method it said that I can't do that in a thread which is not the main one...really weird...

Comment: To use the result of doInBackground() you have to override onPostExecute, the only parameter of this method is the result of doInBackground, in your case is "doc".
You have to manupulate "doc" in this method, if you use this asyncTask once you could create it as a inner class of MyWebViewFragment, then take all your code which use "doc" and put it in onPostExecute body.

Comment: indeed is what i did :) ty